# jirasoapservice and Fix Version

Tags: c#, soap, jira

I need get fixversion from Jira or create new. I use Jira ver. 4.4.4 and velocity plugin 0.2.11.
For new version I can use:

```
RemoteIssue issue = new RemoteIssue();
RemoteVersion version = new RemoteVersion();
version.name = name;
version.id = ...;// what I must write there if I know only name?

issue.reporter = user.name; 
issue.summary = IssueName;
issue.description = IssueName;
issue.fixVersions = new .RemoteVersion[] { version };
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I use the addVersion SOAP method in the JIRA Python CLI code I don't set the id, since JIRA will create it for you. If you are trying to set a Fix Version you will need to use getVersions for the project and find the right one by name.