# Adding a Fix version using JIRA SOAP API

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

I am trying to use the JIRA SOAP API to add a fix version to an issue. I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I still cannot get it to work. Here is the link to the most relevant question, in case someone can make better use of the information there than I can:

[jirasoapservice and Fix Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226013/jirasoapservice-and-fix-version)

I feel like I am doing everyting correct but the fix version is never added. As the answer to the above question says, I do not set an ID and I have made sure that the name is correct by looking at the project's getVersions array.

I am using C#. Thanks for any advice. A working code snippet in C# would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that you can update this field as you would any other field:

```
RemoteFieldValue v = new RemoteFieldValue
{
     id = "fixVersions",
     values = new String[] { wi.Fields[29].Value.ToString() }
};
List<RemoteFieldValue> actionParams = new List<RemoteFieldValue>();
actionParams.Add(v);
jiraSoapServiceService.updateIssue(token, key, actionParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: The answer referenced above is creating a new version. I think since you are referring to a version that already exists you'll need to use the name and the id. Leaving the id blank is only for creating a brand new version.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Unfortunately, after I went back and set the id to a valid one that I got from an existing issue, it still doesn't set the fix version. Everything runs fine, but if I later run code to tell me what the fix version is, it says that the length of my RemoteVersion[] is zero (and therefore I have no fix version). The version never appears on the JIRA website. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is what I have coded so far: `RemoteIssue issue = new RemoteIssue();
            issue.project = Project_Key;
            issue.priority = "3";
            issue.summary = "Summary";
            issue.type = Issue_Type_ID;
            issue.description = "Description";
            RemoteVersion vers = new RemoteVersion();
            vers.name = "PROJ 1.10";
            vers.id = "10182";
            issue.fixVersions = new RemoteVersion[] { vers };
            RemoteIssue returnedIssue = jiraSoapServiceService.createIssue(token, issue);`

Comment: ...Sorry about that format. The code is pretty simple, at least.